# Write to and read from node stream at the same time

Tags: node.js, express, stream, request

I'm trying to download a video file, and then immediately begin streaming it to a client, I have them both working independently as streams but I can't seem to get the functionality I want to work.

```
request.on('response', function (fileResponse) {

    fileResponse.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${__dirname}/../media/${channelName}/${media}.mp4`)

}
```

Streaming an existing video:

```
  const file = fs.createReadStream(`${__dirname}/../media/${channelName}/${media}.mp4`, {start, end});
    const head = {
      'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
      'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
      'Content-Length': chunksize,
      'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
    };

    res.writeHead(206, head);
```

If I put the second piece of code into the response event of the initial piece of code (trying to create the stream and then begin reading it simultaneously) it doesn't work. Is what I'm trying to do technically possible with streams? Thanks!